# Unable to resolve service "Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Tags: zend-framework

I am getting this error 
    Unable to resolve service "Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Comment: There's no default factory for db adapter. you can create a factory and set configuration. Checkout: http://zendframework.github.io/zend-db/adapter/#creating-an-adapter-using-configuration